# Compound Paths and Paths - One single object

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, path

I use an addon for web mapping geospatial PDFs, each object can have `map attributes`, but I have a group:

[image] **>>>** 
[image]

Can I merge them (every letter) into one single object instead of being in a group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select all the Elements you want to merge into a single object …

[image]

… and select `Object > Compund Path > Make` or use the shortcut <kbd>cmd/ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>.

[image]